# SQL Server - Cannot Attach Database (869) or need Import .sbf|.dbf (visual fox pro)

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Long time reader first time poster!

I have a bit of a unique problem which is intensified by my lack of SQL server knowledge. I have SQL Query writing ability but my server side admin is very weak.

Background: 
I am currently working at a very small charity that had a "home-made" Superbase CRM solution which died. The tables which make up this CRM are **.sbf** files which I wasn't able to open with any other software.

Luckily I had exported the necessary tables to **.dbf** files before the Superbase died. Sadly these files do not operate as you would expect, so can't be opened in Access/Excel etc.
After **lots** of searching and testing, I found a work-a-round which came in the form of a **visual fox pro** driver which when installed became an option on the SQL import and export tool. This allowed me to import all the tables to my local SQL database.
For the last 12+ months I have been using the SQL Server studio as tool for data mining and analysis.

Last week we had a consultant IT guy come in and migrate our PC's to O365 (Azure?). I was on holiday at the time but beforehand I had made him aware of my server and the location of the databases. I made it clear that these items were absolutely crucial to the charity. 
He did the migration and ensured that the databases were retained but didn't install a local SQL server but did install SQL Server studio 2012.

The Problem:

I cannot attach the databases.

> *Attach database failed for Server 'DESKTOP-PDTHLCL\SQLSERVER'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)*
>
> *The database 'FINANCE' cannot be opened because it is version 869. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database 'FINANCE'. CREATE DATABASE is
>   aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)*

I have done lots and lots of reading in an attempt to solve this issue, at first thinking that I just need a later install of Local SQL DB but I exhausted that. - I have basically uninstalled and installed every version I could find :-)

From my investigation I have found out that the **869** error is a permissions issue not a version issue (unconfirmed).

In an ideal world I would love to be able to attach my databases to the new server. (Please help)

If this just isn't possible, then my only other solution would be to re-import the **.sbf(.dbf)** files to the new server. 
The problem I have is I cannot remember how I got the visual fox pro drivers to display in the import export software. I have them installed but they don't show.

I would really appreciate any help you can give me, I have spoken to the IT guy and he admitted that this is beyond the realms of his expertise.

[Visual Fox Pro Driver installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j01s8.png)
.
[Visual Fox Pro Driver installed2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvpzz.png)
.[Current Server version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nVXH.png)
Please forgive me if the answers of these questions are already on the forum, sometimes I find the solutions are too technical or not close enough to my specific problem to be helpful.

Thanks

Darren

Comment: [Version 782](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2014/01/sql-server-internal-database-versions.html) is SQL Server 2014, 869 is SQL Server 2017. The version of Management Studio installed is more or less irrelevant, because that's only a GUI connecting to the actual database engine. If the error message is correct it would seem that you now have a SQL Server 2014 instance knocking about on your machine while your DB files were created with a 2017 instance; if that's the case installing LocalDB/Express 2017 would work, if you take care to connect to the right instance name.

Comment: Thank you for coming back so quickly. I have added an image to the opening post to show my current server version.

Comment: `machine\sqlserver` is almost certainly not a LocalDB instance, even if you have 2019 LocalDB installed. Use `sqllocaldb i` to list instances, and/or `sqllocaldb c` to create one. (Recent versions of Management Studio compatible with 2019 can be [downloaded separately](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms).)

Comment: And this doc explains what a LocalDB instance is and how it differs from a service-based instance.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: `C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb v`
**Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2000.5)**
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb i`
**MSSQLLocalDB**
`C:\WINDOWS\system32>sqllocaldb c`
**LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" created with version 15.0.2000.5.**

Comment: Well there you go, and now connecting to it should be possible (using the name `.\MSSQLLocalDB`).

Comment: It works! Thank you. I created a new server in cmd prompt and specified the version. Databases attached. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> The database 'FINANCE' cannot be opened because it is version 869.
>   This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database 'FINANCE'. CREATE DATABASE is
>   aborted. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

Means that the database files are from a SQL Server 2017 instance and you're attempting to attach (or restore) them on an earlier version of SQL Server (SQL Server 2014).

To resolve, just install the correct version of SQL Server, or upgrade the instance to SQL Server 2017 or SQL Server 2019.

Comment: Thank you for replying I currently have version: **Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (15.0.2000.5)** installed. I have tried all versions from 2012 to 2019